# Taxonomy custom post type URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy

I have created a custom post of type "job". I created taxonomies. I would like the urls to be done like this.
examplesite.com/job/categorie/page because for the moment in the url there is only the type of post "job". I did a lot of research I came across various solutions, but without success the pots found in the forums dates from several years and I would like to avoid using a plugin.

Here is my code, in bold I put what I found for the moment on the forums, the most consistent. I'm pretty lost at this level

````
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Carrière',
        'singular_name' => 'Carrière',
        'add_new' => 'Ajouter un emploi',
        'add_new_item' => 'Ajouter un emploi',
        'edit_item' => 'Editer un emploi',
        'new_item' => 'Nouvel un emploi',
        'all_items' => 'Tous les emplois',
        'view_item' => 'Voir emploi',
        'search_items' => 'Chercher un emploi',
        'not_found' => 'Aucun emploi',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Aucun emploi trouvé dans la corbeille',
        'menu_name' => 'Carrières'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'Page détails des emplois',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        **'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'type-job/%cat_job%'),**
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-businessman',

    );
    register_post_type('job', $args );

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Categories',
        'new_item_name' => 'Name cat',
        'parent_item' => 'Cat parent',
    );
    
    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels, 
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'public' => true,
        **'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'type-job'),**
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'type-career', 'job', $args );

}
add_action('init', 'cpt'); ```
````